# Mysql Query returning record count is more than returning rows and i want all rows

Tags: mysql

```
select

 (select sum(calls) from(select count(distinct callid_app) as calls,parent_id as area_id from fp_data as f inner join data_entities as d on d.unique_id=f.from_branch where f.type='Ext/In' and (date_time BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-09 23:59:59') and (weekday(date_time)<=4) and (hour(date_time) between 9 and 16) and d.parent_id in(6,13,21,27) and ignore_call!=1 and d.unique_id>0 group by d.unique_id)as total_calls group by area_id) as t, 

(select sum(calls) from (select count(distinct callid_app) as calls,parent_id as col from fp_data as f inner join data_entities as d on d.unique_id=f.from_branch where f.type='Ext/In' and (date_time BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-09 23:59:59') and (weekday(date_time)<=4) and (hour(date_time) between 9 and 16) and d.parent_id in (6,13,21,27)  and  seg_other_value='1' and start_reason ='[New Call]' and d.unique_id>0 group by unique_id) as calls group by col) as t2                                   from fp_data as f inner join data_entities as d on d.unique_id=f.from_branch
```

giving me error :  `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

sum of `id` is `group by`, so its giving more than one row and i want all these row, so Please tell me what is the solution

AS i Want result should be like

```
         t, t2
         94, 56
         42  43
         15  76
         75  78
```

Comment: I can't even read your query.  Please _format_ it by adding four spaces to each line of code.  With regard to the error, it is self-explanatory: you have a subquery in your select list which is returning more than one value, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: so than what is the solution if all i want all four rows.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: @P.salmon : Please check the question block again i have added what i m expecting in result

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUM(calls) t, NULL t2
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT callid_app) AS calls, parent_id AS area_id
    FROM
        fp_data AS f
    INNER JOIN data_entities AS d ON d.unique_id = f.from_branch
    WHERE
        f.type = 'Ext/In'
            AND (date_time BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-09 23:59:59')
            AND (WEEKDAY(date_time) <= 4)
            AND (HOUR(date_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 16)
            AND d.parent_id IN (6 , 13, 21, 27)
            AND ignore_call != 1
            AND d.unique_id > 0
    GROUP BY d.unique_id) AS total_calls
    GROUP BY area_id 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        NULL t, SUM(calls) t2
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT callid_app) AS calls, parent_id AS col
    FROM
        fp_data AS f
    INNER JOIN data_entities AS d ON d.unique_id = f.from_branch
    WHERE
        f.type = 'Ext/In'
            AND (date_time BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-09 23:59:59')
            AND (WEEKDAY(date_time) <= 4)
            AND (HOUR(date_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 16)
            AND d.parent_id IN (6 , 13, 21, 27)
            AND seg_other_value = '1'
            AND start_reason = '[New Call]'
            AND d.unique_id > 0
    GROUP BY unique_id) AS calls
    GROUP BY col)z
```

You can try above query.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: facing same error :Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: able to manage the derived table alias but it result is showing like t,t2 has total 8 row , whereas  t col has 4 row data and t2 has null data  and next four row t has null data and t2 has a data

Comment: Yes, but that exactly what you want?

Comment: t, t2
         94, 56
         42  43
         15  76
         75  78

Answer (score 0):

got it

Select t,t2 from

(SELECT

```
    SUM(calls) t, area_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT callid_app) AS calls, parent_id AS area_id
FROM
    fp_data AS f
INNER JOIN data_entities AS d ON d.unique_id = f.from_branch
WHERE
    f.type = 'Ext/In'
        AND (date_time BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-09 23:59:59')
        AND (WEEKDAY(date_time) <= 4)
        AND (HOUR(date_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 16)
        AND d.parent_id IN (6 , 13, 21, 27)
        AND ignore_call != 1
        AND d.unique_id > 0
GROUP BY d.unique_id) AS total_calls
GROUP BY area_id) as total_calls inner join 
(SELECT 
    area_id, SUM(calls) t2
FROM
    (SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT callid_app) AS calls, parent_id AS area_id
FROM
    fp_data AS f
INNER JOIN data_entities AS d ON d.unique_id = f.from_branch
WHERE
    f.type = 'Ext/In'
        AND (date_time BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-09 23:59:59')
        AND (WEEKDAY(date_time) <= 4)
        AND (HOUR(date_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 16)
        AND d.parent_id IN (6 , 13, 21, 27)
        AND seg_other_value = '1'
        AND start_reason = '[New Call]'
        AND d.unique_id > 0
GROUP BY unique_id) AS calls
GROUP BY area_id) as branch_total_calls on total_calls.area_id=branch_total_calls.area_id
```